# Google Sheets - Protect monthly range script needs monthly triggers at specified date and time

Tags: date, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to request help with a script Im trying to put together.

Linked is my test spreadsheet including the script I currently have on the second sheet.

The idea is that this sheet will be copied individually to a group of people. Each person will get their own sheet, editable only by them and myself. It does not get shared any further. Each day the person will add a value into the corresponding day's cell.
On the last day of each month at 8pm, I would like to protect (lock) the cells for that month, to stop the person changing any values that they previously entered.

I have put a repeating script together with a function for each month, covering each range. The problem I'm having is creating triggers that will run the function on the required day. If I set a monthly trigger, they will all trigger at the same time at the end of the first month. Ideally I need individual triggers that will run once a year on the specified date and time for each individual function.

Is this possible? Is there a better way of doing this?
I also realise that I will need to give permissions for each function run, and possibly for each individual copy of the sheet I give to said persons. Is there a clever way around that?

Im also thinking another approach would be for the script to trigger each monthly function 'on open' if the relative date has passed. For example, on Open, if Date is Feb 1st, lock January range, and so on.

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

*(Note: the true sheet I copied my script and layout from starts this section at Column U, which is why I have minimised Columns A-T).*

Test Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13z8eWpo6oislkGX3USifLWqh5sz3DsJpSY1YyqNLrx8/edit?usp=sharing